# How can I type a conditional return type based on an input parameter

Tags: typescript

I am trying to ensure that a function returns a specific type based on a parameter. How can I make typescript understand what I want here ?

```
type A = 'a'
type B = 'b'

const func = <Type extends A | B>(arg: Type): Type extends A ? 'a1': 'b1' => {
    //Type '"a1"' is not assignable to type 'Type extends "a" ? "a1" : "b1"'.(2322)
    if (arg === 'a') return 'a1'
    
     // Type '"b1"' is not assignable to type 'Type extends "a" ? "a1" : "b1"'.(2322)
    return 'b1'
}

// Output type is a1 here
const a1 = func('a')
// Output type is b1 here
const b1 = func('b')
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDkBDJBYAUKSUBCCyARhplgMYD2AdgM7BQBmArteYQDwAq40EAHsAjUAJrVhQAPvgB8AChQAnAOYAuKD0gBKdZr6DhYiQH5kKAIxJ1SIpYQyoAbyxRXUAJaMoClQniJUJC0oRQhgZkVqM0ssFzdQ8MjiGMwAX1jMAHpMqAB5ZmAwAqgcaHdxCygACwhQihp6KFoqymYAGxE8CBhzQhY2OUCtLGy8gqKGUo9xW2raiHq6BmbWjq68XsR+8kGSLSA)

Answer (score 1):

While it's usually a good idea to use [Function Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) for such scenarios it is also possible to work with a custom type map that contains all possible return types based on your [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) parameter.

```
type A = 'a';
type B = 'b';

type ResultMap = {
  [K in A]: 'a1';
} & {
  [L in B]: 'b1';
};

function func<T extends A | B>(arg: T): ResultMap[T] {
  const resultMap: ResultMap = {
    a: 'a1',
    b: 'b1',
  };

  if (arg in resultMap) {
    return resultMap[arg];
  }

  throw new Error('Invalid argument');
}

const a1 = func('a'); // 'a1'
const b1 = func('b'); // 'b1'
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDkBDJBuAsAKFJKAQgsgEYY457QBKEAzgK4A2wAsimMQN45RQDaAaSgBLAHawAugC5kKAIzlsAXygAyKD2x9%20AGVESCM0oqwqzOAGYMxAY2AiA9hOt2APABUoEAB7AIYgAmdLBQAD6EAHwAFCgATgDmsh4AlLK0jCzsYPwekpq8ULbOdMBQcfTMbBzplVkc3IV8KLKoigA0TVAkrSQdhcoW2qKWULGJBuV11WApBcN8FcAMcRIVmTP88QmSZnzKFMPAABZxjgDuUGIQlwCicWdx0UgAkmIAbihMIoFQ2wwAWwCwCQKTMB2wOGKYlKf3kxFctmeaDBUAA9Gi5IooSUyn0ETYkUgyKiMSYkDggA)